# how to save <a> items as a variable then append to a DIV as functional HTML

Tags: jquery, html, list, hyperlink, append

I have a menu made up of nested lists (extract below), each item links to another page, when the user mouses over the first level list item, a variable stores the html within that item, which is then is passed to another DIV. Here's how the list is written:

```
 <ul id="siteMenu">
 <li><a href="shop-for-yarn">Colours</a>
<ul >
<li><a href="linktopage">Blacks/Greys</a></li>
<li><a href="linktopage">Blues</a></li>
<li><a href="linktopage">Greens</a></li>
<li><a href="linktopage">Mauve/Lilacs</a></li>
<li><a href="linktopage">Oranges</a></li>
<li><a href="linktopage">Yellows</a></li>
<li><a href="linktopage">Whites/Pastel</a></li>
</ul>
 </li>
 </ul>
```

Everything seems to be working, EXCEPT that the list loses the links when appended to the DIV.

This is the bit of JQuery...

```
$("ul#siteMenu li") .mouseover(function() {

    var list = $(this) .find("ul") .html();

$("#menuDisplay") .empty() .append("<ul>"+list+"</ul>");

});
```

If anyone can see why this might be happening, please let me know, thanks.

Comment: Change this: $("ul#siteMenu > li") .mouseover(...

Comment: You might try using `.html()` rather than `.empty().append()`.

Comment: Thanks, both these improve my code, though still have same problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("ul#siteMenu > li").mouseover(function() {
    var list = $(this).find("ul");
    $("#menuDisplay").empty().append(list);
});
```

Comment: It is highly recommended to add some explanations or comments to your code. Some people might not always understand what the code does.

Comment: Sorry, will try and be more descriptive next time.

Comment: Have worked out the problem! Seems a though the DIV #menuDisplay was opening under another DIV that was masking the text! CSS error not jQuery! All your comments still helped me streamline the code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.clone` to capture the content into a variable and using `append()` to apply it to the new `<div>`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("ul li").mouseover(function() {
        var list = $(this).find("ul").clone();
        $('#menuDisplay').empty().append(list);
    });
});
```